# getting the output of "find" in a CSV

Tags: linux, sed, find

I've got a project where I'm trying to collect all the files on a linux system into a CSV to be dumped into a DB.

my script has

```
FIND_CMD $TARGET $OPTS -xdev $FS -printf "%h,%f,%y,%s,%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%.2TS\n"
```

But the problem is that I have filenames `%f` and directory names `%h` with commas in them.

So then I thought I could just put each item in quotes and that won't be a problem.

```
$FIND_CMD $TARGET $OPTS -xdev $FS -printf "\"%h\",\"%f\",\"%y\",\"%s\",\"%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%.2TS\"\n"
```

But then I discovered that I have filenames with quotes in them :(

So i'm trying to figure out how I can sub " with "" with quotes around the whole thing.

Example:

> "/home""dir","file,name","f","1024","2016-11-04 11:11:00"

So i'm wondering if there's a way for me to call `sed` as part of `-printf`so i can tell the find command to replace "s with ""s

My other thought was to replace the delimiter in my find command with something else like | but i'm likely to run into the same problem if a filename or directory name has a | in (which is possible)

Are there any other creative solutions to this that i may not be thinking of?

Comment: Write a script that reads filenames on its standard input, and formats the CSV line as you want (it can use `stat` to get all the attributes). Then pipe the output of `find ... -print` to that.

Comment: Nul is not allowed in a filename (which is why `find` has `print0`) so that might make a good separator... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems

Comment: @MarkSetchell i think that would do it. Then i wouldn't need to put quotes around each value. Just using the NUL byte as the separator means I can put "" where "s are and my CSV reader will be able to handle it. Thanks! I'll give that a shot!

Comment: @MarkSetchell your suggestion works. -printf "%h\0,%f\0,%y\0,%s\0,%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%.2TS\n" did it perfectly. If you would like to post an answer, I'll be happy to mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using NUL as a delimiter in your CSV since that is not a valid character in a Linux filename/pathname - [Wikipedia refernce](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems).

That is also the reason that the `find` command provides `-print0` and that tools such as **Perl** and **GNU Parallel** have corresponding switches giving rise to:

```
find . -name '*.orig' -print0 | perl -n0e unlink
```

and

```
find . -print0 | parallel -0 ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion.